# Is there a more efficient way to manage an IF statement?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a total of 102 values associated with a fieldname called `ArrivedFlag`.

Then I have a `TextBox` control with an id of `txtFlag` on the markup page.

In my codebehind, I have an if statement that says:

```
If txtFlag <> "value1" and txtFlag <> "another value" Then
  lblMessage.Text ="You don't have the ability to view details"
end if
```

This works fine.

However, given that there are 102 values, I feel that doing an IF statement 102 times is a bit inefficient.

Does anyone know of a better way to handle this?

```
Dim allowedFlags = New List(Of String)() 

With { _
    "value1", _
    "another value"
}
End With
If Not allowedFlags.Contains(txtFlag) Then
    lblMessage.Text = "You don't have the ability to view details"
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the values to a list,and then use .Contains

```
// hopefully you can get the 102 strings from an xml document or db
var listOfFlags = new List<string> { "value1", "another value", .... };

if (!listOfFlags.Contains(txtFlag))
{
  lblMessage.Text = "you dont' have ..."
}
```

Comment: After some slight modifications, this worked well for me. Thank you and thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

A "switch" statement would be cleaner, though 102 "cases" would still be kind of messy.
If you went with a strategy pattern, you would likely experience some measure "class explosion".

I'd probably start with a switch statement and then look at extracting some common behaviors and heading towards a strategy pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Put your allowed values into an array and then just query whether the user's choice is in the array:

```
if(!allowedFlags.Contains(txtFlag))
   lblMessage.Text ="You don't have the ability to view details";
```

Even better you can use a `HashSet<string>` for the allowed values so you have O(1) lookup time.

Comment: Thanks alot experts for your time and assistance. I like Jason's and BrokenGlass's solutions for their ease but I am having a hard time getting it to work. I keep getting, "You don't have the ability to view details" even when I select from the list I created. I have updated current code above.